# CV skeleton with pst-asr package?

Tags: pstricks, pst-asr

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-xkey,pst-asr,graphicx}\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}

\asr \3p{\textepsilon}{\textltailm} \endasr

\end{document}
```

Is there anyway I can use CV skeleton instead of x?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the symbol within the `\asr` construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-asr,tipa}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\xsymb}{}
\newcommand{\cons}{\renewcommand{\xsymb}{c}}% Consonant
\newcommand{\vowl}{\renewcommand{\xsymb}{v}}% Vowel

\asr[tssym=\xsymb] \3\cons p \vowl{\textepsilon}\cons{\textltailm} \endasr

\end{document}
```

The idea is to set the `tssymb` key to some macro (`\xsymb` in the above case). Then, with every consonant/vowel *switch* you call `\cons`/`\vowel` which updates the macro `\xsymb`.

Comment: This looks complicated, but thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default timing slot symbol to be empty, and then manually place `C` and `V` on the timing slot tier. I've explained more in the code below, which needs to be run with XeLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-asr}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign} % selects a math font to match Charis SIL
\usepackage{fontspec} % for font declaration in XeLaTeX
\setmainfont{Charis SIL} % this needs to go after `\usepackage{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts, % allows \@ to expand to \tierput and \- to expand to \assoc
    tssym=, % the timing slot symbol ($\times$ by default) is set to be blank so that you can override it manually
    ts=0pt (C) % C and V are taller than the default timing slot symbol, so this sets the height of this tier to the height of C
}

\asr
\3 % gives you a syllable with three timing slots
| % begins a stretch that the parser will ignore
\@(0,ts){C} % puts C in the 1st timing slot
\@(1,ts){V} % puts V in the 2nd timing slot
\@(2,ts){C} % puts C in the 3rd timing slot
| % finishes the stretch that the parser will ignore
pɛɱ
\endasr

\end{document}
```

### Simplified version

This code can be simplified to `\asr \3|\CVC|pɛɱ \endasr` by defining a macro for the entire timing slot tier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-asr}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign} % selects a math font to match Charis SIL
\usepackage{fontspec} % for font declaration in XeLaTeX
\setmainfont{Charis SIL} % this needs to go after `\usepackage{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts, % allows \@ to expand to \tierput and \- to expand to \assoc
    tssym=, % the timing slot symbol ($\times$ by default) is set to be blank so that you can override it manually
    ts=0pt (C) % C and V are taller than the default timing slot symbol, so this sets the height of this tier to the height of C
}

\newcommand{\CVC}{\@(0,ts){C}\@(1,ts){V}\@(2,ts){C}} % puts all of the timing slot tier into a macro

\asr \3|\CVC|pɛɱ \endasr % make sure to delimit the macro within ||, which makes the parser ignore it

\end{document}
```

### Multiple syllables

Beware that if you want to put more than one syllable together, you have to define the macro for the entire `asr`, not syllable by syllable, because the timing slot indices continue across all the syllables within the `asr`.

Here's an example. The `\CCVC` macro puts the CCVC on the first four slots of the `asr`, on top of the CVC put there by the `\CVC` macro.

```
\newcommand{\CVC}{\@(0,ts){C}\@(1,ts){V}\@(2,ts){C}}
\newcommand{\CCVC}{\@(0,ts){C}\@(1,ts){C}\@(2,ts){V}\@(3,ts){C}}

\asr \4|\CCVC|pɾɔm\3|\CVC|pɛɱ \endasr
```

[image]

One possible workaround is to define a macro for the whole `asr`:

```
\newcommand{\CCVCCVC}{\@(0,ts){C}\@(1,ts){C}\@(2,ts){V}\@(3,ts){C}\@(4,ts){C}\@(5,ts){V}\@(6,ts){C}}

\asr |\CCVCCVC|\4pɾɔm\3pɛɱ \endasr
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate it, Jason. I will try all the approaches. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I tried this one for multiple syllables: `\asr \3|\CVC|pɛɱ \endasr \quad \asr \3|\CVC|pɛɱ \endasr`

Comment: Sure, there are lots of ways to make it work, depending on your needs. Breaking the syllables into two `asr`s wouldn't work if you wanted to put a tier above the syllable level, for instance, but if you don't need that, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi, Jason. `\asr |\CV|ha \endasr \quad \asr |\CV|hi \endasr` works for multiple syllables. Thanks again for your valuable input!